# Different between anonymous function expression and named function expression (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript

I have the code below:

```
//anonymous function expression
var a = function() {
    return 3;
}

//named function expression
var a = function bar() {
    return 3;
}
```

So, what is the different between them ? (technical, usage)

Comment: No specific difference, but using named functions can improve the readability of stacktraces in the event of a crash

Comment: possible duplicate of [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main differences are

- You can inspect the function name (for example stack traces are more readable)
- The function can be recursive

Note that a function like

```
var fibo = function(n) {
    return n<2 ? 1 : fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2);
};
```

is not really recursive as its body will call whatever `fibo` is bound to at the moment of the call (so it will not call itself if `fibo` is later assigned to something else). The version

```
var f = function fibo(n) {
    return n<2 ? 1 : fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2);
};
```

is instead really recursive and will keep calling itself no matter what `f` is later bound to.